# Return reference to unique_ptr in google mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have problem returning a reference to a unique pointer in google mock.
I have an object Foo, with a method operate(), that I’m trying to test in google test/google mock framework:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(BarInterface &bar) : bar{bar} {};
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
  void operate() { bar.getBaz()->startMeUp(); }
private:
  BarInterface &bar;
};
```

The test class looks like this:

```
using ::testing::StrictMock;
using ::testing::ReturnRef;

class FooTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
  StrictMock<BarMock> barMock;
  std::unique_ptr<StrictMock<BazMock>> bazMock {new StrictMock<BazMock>()}; // This might be incorrect

  Foo *foo;
  virtual void SetUp() {
    foo = new Foo(barMock);
  }

  virtual void TearDown() {
    delete foo;
  }
};

TEST_F(FooTest, BasicTest) {
  EXPECT_CALL(barMock, getBaz()).WillOnce(ReturnRef(bazMock)); // Gives compilation error
  EXPECT_CALL(*bazMock, startMeUp()); // Gives compilation error
  foo->operate();
}
```

As you  can see I have two objects that are mocked, Bar and Baz. 
Baz mock has one method, startMeUp():

```
class BazInterface {
public:
  virtual ~BazInterface() = default;
  virtual void startMeUp() = 0;
};

class BazMock : public BazInterface {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(startMeUp, void());
};
```

The Bar method getBaz() returns a reference to a unique pointer according to:

```
class BarInterface {
public:
  virtual ~BarInterface() = default;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>& getBaz() = 0;
};

class BarMock : public BarInterface {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(getBaz, std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>&());
};
```

The problem is (at least) that I can not get the two EXPECT_CALL() right. I’ve tried to return the bazMock in several ways, but I always get compilation error.
I’ve also tried to simplify the problem by instead returning a reference to a shared_ptr and even an ordinary pointer, but I couldn’t get that compiling either.
Can someone please help me to get it right?

Here is the compilation output:

```
gmock-actions.h: In instantiation of 'testing::internal::ReturnRefAction<T>::Impl<F>::Result testing::internal::ReturnRefAction<T>::Impl<F>::Perform(const ArgumentTuple&) [with F = std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>&(); T = std::unique_ptr<testing::StrictMock<BazMock> >; testing::internal::ReturnRefAction<T>::Impl<F>::Result = std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>&; testing::internal::ReturnRefAction<T>::Impl<F>::ArgumentTuple = std::tuple<>]':
foo_test.cc:30:1:   required from here
gmock-actions.h:683:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'testing::internal::ReturnRefAction<std::unique_ptr<testing::StrictMock<BazMock> > >::Impl<std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>&()>::Result {aka std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>&}' from expression of type 'std::unique_ptr<testing::StrictMock<BazMock> >'
   return ref_;
```

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to a smart pointer? Is the caller expected to change it to point to another object or release it?

Comment: No, it points to the same Baz-object during the whole "program lifetime"

Comment: "*Gives compilation error*", namely ?

Comment: I've now added the compilation output to the question above.

Comment: @Pucko In that case I would return a reference (or possibly a raw pointer) to the object itself, not the smart pointer. When you return a reference to the smart pointer you give callers the opportunity to reset it which would be a program error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best fix would be to change the interface of `BarInterface` to return reference to `BazInterface` instead of reference `unique_ptr`. There is no need to expose the pointer to `BarInterface` users.
If you insist on returning reference to `unique_ptr` do it like this:

```
class BarMock : public BarInterface
{
public:
    BarMock(std::unique_ptr<BazInterface> baz) {this->baz = std::move(baz);}

    override std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>& getBaz(){
        getBazWrapped();
        return baz;
    }
    MOCK_METHOD0(getBazWrapped, void());
private:
    std::unique_ptr<BazInterface> baz;
};
```

And in `FooTest`

```
BazMock * bazMock { new <StrictMock<BazMock> };
BarMock barMock { std::unique_ptr<BazInterface>(bazMock)};
```